# Two dropdown-menues which are in relation to each other with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to create two dropdown-menues which are in relation to each other. A "job-maincategory" and a "job-subcategory".

If you chose a "job-maincategory" in the "job-subcategory" only the jobs which are in relation to the "job-maincategory" should apear. I try to realise it with javascript-ajax. Sadly, I don´t get the thing to work and I´m looking for help.

Here is the link to the online example im working on:

[Example](http://www.fabiansquinobal.com/kategorie.php)

Here is the code of the mainfile with the two dropdownmenus:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dayjob - Kategorien</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/categorydropdown.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php

$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$passwordmysql = "xxxxxx";
$dbname ="xxxxxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $passwordmysql, $dbname);    
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $sqlgetcategory = "SELECT `jobcategory` FROM `jobcategory` ORDER BY `jobcategory` ASC";
    $jobcategory = $conn->query($sqlgetcategory);

        echo "<select name=\"selectjobcategorysubchoicemain\" id=\"selectjobcategorysubchoicemain\">";
        echo "<option value=\"\" disabled selected>Hauptategorie</option>";
        while ($schleife = $jobcategory->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<option value=".$schleife['jobcategory'].">".$schleife['jobcategory']."</option>";
        }
        echo "<option value=\"nocategory\">Sonstiges..</option>";
        echo "</select>";


?>

        <select id="selectjobcatergorysub">
            <option value="0">- Select -</option>
        </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript-file which gets triggered on a change of the "job-maincategory":

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#selectjobcategorysubchoicemain").change(function(){
            var data = $("#selectjobcategorysubchoicemain").serialize();
            window.alert(data);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'categorysubdropdown.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    window.alert(response);

                    $("#selectjobcatergorysub").empty();


                    $("#selectjobcatergorysub").append("<option value='"+response+"'>"+response+"</option>");     


                }
            });
        });

    });
```

And here is the .php-file which gets triggered from ajax of the javascript-file:

```
<?php

$servername = "xxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$passwordmysql = "xxxxxx";
$dbname ="xxxxxx";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $passwordmysql, $dbname);    
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");


    $choicemain = $_POST['selectjobcategorysubchoicemain'];



    $sqlgetcategorysub = "SELECT `jobcategory`, `jobcategorysub` FROM `jobcategorysub` WHERE `jobcategory` = '$choicemain' ORDER BY `jobcategorysub` ASC";

    $jobcategorysub = $conn->query($sqlgetcategorysub);


    $jobsubcategory_arr = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($jobcategorysub) ){
    $subjobcat = $row['jobcategorysub'];
    $jobsubcategory_arr = array("jobcategorysub" => $subjobcat);
    }

echo json_encode($jobsubcategory_arr);

?>
```

The Problem at the moment is that I only get back "[object Object]" as response from php and i don´t know why. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: `alert()` can't display the contents of objects. Do a `console.log(response)` and check your console instead and you'll see what the response actually contains.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I will read up on that. - I´m a beginner.

Comment: `json_encode($jobsubcategory_arr);` will create a _json object_ which is what you're currently returning.

Comment: There is a potential issue with the while loop on the rows. You are assigning them over the same variables (instead of adding to the array), so you will only end up with the last row of data in the json.

Comment: I get that back in the console: "Object
jobcategorysub
:
"Rasen mähen"
__proto__
:
Object" - which is now in the live-link.

Comment: @IncredibleHat - I´m aware of that. At the moment I only want to get some content in my "job-subcategory"

Comment: You retrieve an object: try 
    $("#selectjobcatergorysub").append("<option value='"+response. jobcategorysub +"'>"+response. jobcategorysub +"</option>");

There are many others issues in your script, you retrieve only one result, but I think you want more than one result, you have SQL vulnerability aswell

Comment: @BenoitNgô - Yeah.. thank you - Now I have one result in my in my "subcategory". Can you give me please a hint how i should change my "while-loop" to get them all?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - I red the article of SQL Injections and know quiet the same as before. How could someone else can make a "SQL Injection" without the "username" and "password" of my mysql-database?

Comment: @Andrewstevens - Then you should read a bit more. There are many ways people can make SQL Injection attacks without the need of any username or password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of the issues you were facing, here is a complete rewrite of your ajax php. The prior example I provided used a method your server must not have installed (fetch_all). As such, I have rewritten my example in light of that.

This will cover sql injection protection, as you are passing in a _POST variable from the world. Anyone can manipulate the value of that variable to take control of your sql query. This is why `prepare` is so important, and a must.

The output is now done using bind_result (and sql reduced to just one field return needed), since you do not have access to the easier one-line-method fetch_all. This is also adjusted to only return a single array of the values you need. NOT an array of objects (reduces needless {name:value} waste).

***categorysubdropdown.php***:

```
<?php
$servername    = "xxxxxx";// you really should keep this db setup in an include, 
$username      = "xxxxxx";// and then do include_once('/dbsetup.php');
$passwordmysql = "xxxxxx";
$dbname        = "xxxxxx";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $passwordmysql, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

if ( !empty($_POST['selectjobcategorysubchoicemain']) ) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT jc.jobcategorysub 
                            FROM jobcategorysub as jc 
                            WHERE jc.jobcategory = ? 
                            ORDER BY jc.jobcategorysub ASC");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['selectjobcategorysubchoicemain']);
    $stmt->bind_result($jobcategorysub);
    $stmt->execute();

    $output = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) { $output[] = $jobcategorysub; }
    echo json_encode( $output );
}
?>
```

Your ajax should be this to work with the php output:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'categorysubdropdown.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);// to debug json return
        $("#selectjobcatergorysub").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ){
            $("#selectjobcatergorysub").append(
                 "<option value='"+ response[i] +"'>"+ response[i] +"</option>"
            );
        }
    }
});
```

This loops on the `response` Array for each row by its `length` (which is an Array length, not character length), and then accesses the field by the `i` index. No need for object subnames, as the output from php does not include them.

This has all be tested on my older server that doesn't have fetch_all installed as well, and verified error free.

Comment: Thank you. I´ll try that immediately, but one thing I don´t understand. ".lenght" gives back the numbers of characters of a string? Why you use that here? I saw it before and it makes no sense to me. I want to run the loop as long as objects are in my array, not as long as many characters are in my string?

Comment: `response.length` returns the number of items in the array. `response` is an object, it has a method of `.length` which returns the size of the object array.

Comment: Not to be confused with `response[i].jobcategorysub.length`, which returns the string `response[i].jobcategorysub` length.

Comment: Ah, so only if it was a string it gives back the number of characters?

Comment: Correct. It can be confusing since .length works for both string and Array. However since the ajax is returning with `dataType: 'json'`, it is taking that response and turning it into an object, which is also an Array of rows.

Comment: Hi again. Sorry to bother you again, but there is sadly an issue with the mysql-querry. Is it possible that you only can use bind_param to insert values? =) - When i google it, I only find examples with "inserts". Or is there maybe a syntax-error?

Comment: Prepared statements are for ANY sql query that has variable data you wish to insert 'safely'. Such as user input, get vars, post vars, and such. It protects the SQL from injection attacks and also properly escapes data that could otherwise break the sql. If there is a sql error ... please let me know what the actual error says? (I updated my answer with more details, to maybe make it clearer)

Comment: Okay, thank you for the Information. I don´t know to get to the error-msg because the .php file doesn´t get displayed :D - I´m a newbee... But it must be the SQL because when i replace it with my old it works. With yours the subcategorys do not get loaded into the dropdownmenu.

Comment: I figured out what may have happened. I was using `fetch_all`, which must not be present on your server (its part of mysqlnd). I have completely rewritten my answer in light of this finding. The new code should work better now (if not a little more verbose).

Comment: Thank you very very much. Thank you for your time, you realy helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

As asked, Here is how to solve:

1. Change your php script to return an array with all result:

PHP:

```
    // Init the displayed array
    $ret = [];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($jobcategorysub) ){
      $subjobcat = $row['jobcategorysub'];
      $jobsubcategory_arr = array("jobcategorysub" => $subjobcat);
      // Add each line to the array to display
      $ret[] = $jobsubcategory_arr;
    }
    // display the array as json
    echo json_encode($ret);
```

2. In your javascript, the construction of `<option>` is now wrong:

javascript:

```
// in your callback, you loop over the array returned
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
   // Here you access one of the result (a line of the array)
   var r = response[i];
    // Construct your select by accessing variable from your object
    $("#selectjobcatergorysub").append("<option value='"+r.jobcategorysub +"'>"+r.jobcategorysub +"</option>");
}
```

Now: In your PHP you construct an array of array, each row contains one   result, so each row contains one of your desired data. In your javascript, you construct the `<select>` from the array returned.
If you are new to PHP i recommend to use a framework which help in being protected by most known vulnerability.